# Integrate $\frac{x}{(x^4+1)^2 \sqrt{(x^2-x+1)}}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, radical-equations

Evaluate the indefinite integral, $$\int\frac{x}{(x^4+1)^2 \sqrt{(x^2-x+1)}} \mathrm{d}x$$

Found this problem in a mathematics group site, but the solution was never posted.  I suspect it cannot be solved with pen and paper. Online integration sites failed to complete it also. Is it possible? Tried integration by parts, trig substitution. Problem is the denominator: product of the square root of a quadratic and a 4th degree polynomial squared.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  And no, it isn't very nice.

We can deal with $\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$ by the substitution $2x=1+\sqrt{3}\tan\theta$.  This converts the integral to an integral of a rational function of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$, so you can use the $t$-substitution to get it as the integral of a rational function of $t$ (i.e., $x=\frac12+\sqrt{3}t/(1+t^2)$).  Note that you need to factor a high degree polynomial in $t$, and this is not very nice.